# Where is CurrentAppSimulator Class in Windows.Services.Store namespace?

Tags: windows, uwp, store

Where is CurrentAppSimulator Class in Windows.Services.Store namespace ?

I wonder why this class is removed?  How MSFT expects developers to do testing?

Testing on live store is reckless, insensible.

isn't there a way to test all code paths in the purchasing process. ?

Regards

Comment: From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentappsimulator): *"For more information, see [In-app purchases and trials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/in-app-purchases-and-trials)."* Does this not answer your question or did you simply not read it?

Comment: I had read. but do you think its a solution ?   How many addon you will create and buy to carry out a testing ?  I cannot revoke my addon license.  I have to buy to test the paid addon... There is no temporary credit card numbers that i can use to test a successful paid or failed  payment flow.    Its a painful workaround not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The `CurrentAppSimulator` Class comes from the `Windows.ApplicationModel.Store` namespace. As @IInspectable mentioned, the document had already said that **The Windows.ApplicationModel.Store namespace is no longer being updated** and
it is recommended that you use the `Windows.Services.Store` namespace instead.

To test your in-app purchase, you could check the [Test your in-app purchase or trial implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/in-app-purchases-and-trials#testing) part of the document, which explains how you could test your in-app purchase. You could create a free add-on for the testing purchase.

Comment: Why the class was not carried forward into Windows.Services.Store namespace ?  Was there any technical issue ?   or atleast some alternative Simulator should have been there to make developers life easy. isn't it ?     Atleast there should be some way to delete acquired license so that you can reuse same addon to continue testing.      Also 'Subscription' should be part of main product pricing structure, instead of giving it as Addon.

Comment: @Neha As the document mentioned, the old `Windows.ApplicationModel.Store` is namespace out of date. The new `Windows.Services.Store` namespace supports the latest add-on types, such as Store-managed consumable add-ons, and is designed to be compatible with future types of products and features supported by Partner Center and the Store. I understand your feelings, if you have other feature requests about the API, you could submit them in the Feedback Hub. You could find the Feedback hub in the Start menu.

Comment: Done.  added to feedback hub.  Thanks.